# Javascript tokenised list to associative collection

Tags: javascript, token, associative-array

I have a large collection of comma delimited tokens, kind of like this:

```
let str = "Rock,Paper,Scissors"; // ... except much bigger.
```

I need to pass over a large set of data, checking whether a parameter is in this list or not. My initial thought was to convert this collection to an object and search on key - there may be better ways. I know that:

```
str.split(",");
```

will give me an array.

```
["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
```

I'm *guessing* this is functionally equivalent to

```
{
    "0": "Rock",
    "1": "Paper",
    "2": "Scissors"
}
```

but that doesn't really help me too much. Is there a way to simply transpose the key and value to give me an useful keyed collection? As in:

```
{
    "Rock":     "0",
    "Paper":    "1",
    "Scissors": "2"
}
```

Naturally a simple loop would do it - just wondered if there's any language built-in way of doing this. And is this even the best way to deal with this problem in Javascript or are there better / more efficient ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, i don't think there is any "built-in" way of doing this. But i think the most elegant way to accomplish exactly what you want is the following:

```
result = str.split(',').reduce(
  function(prev, cur, index) {
    prev[cur] = String(index); 
    return prev;
  }, {});
```

Answer (score 3):

Logically what you want is a *set*. JavaScript is [going to have a Set class soon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), but currently it's not widely available in browsers.

However, given that your keys are strings, you can use an object as a fake set:

```
// populate set
var o = {};
o["Rock"] = true;
// ...add others

// test membership
if (o["Rock"] != null)
  // is in set
```

If you are able to target browsers that support `Set`, then you can just use:

```
var set = new Set(str.split(","));

if (set.has("Rock"))
  // is in set
```

This works in current Chrome and Firefox versions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a simple `for` loop would be the best way to do this:

```
var str ="Rock,Paper,Scissors",
    arr = str.split(","),
    obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    obj[arr[i]] = i;
```

The result:

```
console.log(obj);
-> Object {Rock: 0, Paper: 1, Scissors: 2}
```

Here our `for` loop takes up a measly 2 lines of code. There really isn't much need to simplify this further. If you really wanted you could write your own function to do this though.

```
function arrayToObjectWithValuesAsKeys(array) {
    var obj = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        obj[arr[i]] = i;

    return obj;
}

var obj = arrayToObjectWithValuesAsKeys(str.split(","));
```

Comment: I guess that's why he wrote "Naturally a simple loop would do it" at the end of his question...

Comment: @EasyPush I've added a bit to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I had already tried this out with `var my_coll = {}; str.split( "," ).forEach(function(name){my_coll[name]=true;});` which seems to do the job. Though (a) I'm a little uneasy about `forEach` and (b) I wasn't sure if there was a much more straightforward, efficient and accepted way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

ES5 has map/reduce methods that you could handle every dataset transforming needs.

```
function parse(str) {
    var arr = str.split(",");
    var obj = arr.reduce(function(prev, cur, index) {
        prev[cur] = index; 
        return prev;
    }, {});
    return obj;
}

var str = "Rock,Paper,Scissors"; // ... except much bigger.
console.log(parse(str));
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gq0jc8hc/